# Вывод всех четных и нечетных элементов двумерного массива в другие массивы.Си

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Задание:

С помощью динамического распределения памяти создать двумерный массив 10 х 10, заполненный случайными значениями от -100 до 100. Создать два одномерных массива с первоначальной длиной 0. Затем поместить в первый массив элементы с четным значением, во второй с нечетным.Размер одномерных массивов при добавлении увеличивается на единицу.

Вывод: Двумерный массив и два одномерных.

Не получается вывести все четные и нечетные элементы в одномерных массивах, а не только 10 (Как в первой функции).

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define d 10

int Outputodnomer(int a[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
        printf("%5d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}


int Outputdvumer(int *a[d])
{
    printf("Двумерный массив:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
int odnomer(int *a[d], int mas1[], int mas2[]) {
    int k = 0, n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            if (a[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                mas1[k] = a[i][j];
                k++;
            }
            else {
                mas2[n] = a[i][j];
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int Generation(int *a[d])
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 200 - 101;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, **mas=  { 0 } , *mas1 = { 0 }, *mas2 = { 0 },s;

    mas = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        mas[i] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    mas1 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));
    mas2 = (int*)malloc(d*d * sizeof(int));

    Generation(mas);
    Outputdvumer(mas);
    odnomer(mas, mas1, mas2);
    for (i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        free(mas[i]);
    free(mas);
    printf("Одномерный массив с нечетными числами: \n");
    Outputodnomer(mas1);
    free(mas1);
    printf("Одномерный массив с четными числами: \n");
    Outputodnomer(mas2);
    free(mas2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/5j3Z4g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k и n  (реальные размеры) должны быть глобальными переменными (и их лучше переобозвать пологичнее) и их нужно использовать как второй аргумент `Outputodnomer`

```
   int Outputodnomer(int a[], int Count){
      for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
```

генерация в указанном диапазоне чуть отличается:

```
a[i][j] = rand() % 201 - 100;
```

Кроме того, задание требует изменения размеров одномерных массивов - полагаю, что это всё же означает их постоянную реаллокацию (что, конечно, глупо с точки зрения реальной работы)

Comment: У меня как раз проблемы в понимании этого. Как передать значение k и n из функции odnomer в функцию Outputodnomer?

Comment: в понимании чего именно?

Comment: Я не особо понимаю что нужно сделать, чтобы воплотить эту логику в коде)

Comment: Показал модификацию. А объявление переменных перенести после #define d 10

Comment: Объявляю Count, просто "int Count;"? Нужно же приравнять к значению k и n из функции odnomer?

Comment: Только вопрос остается "как?")